# Necessary and sufficient condition for the space of continuous functions to be a closed linear subspace of Banach function space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

This is the definition of Banach function space :
[image]

This is the theorem which I have mention in the title of the question.
( $I = [0;1]$ in this theorem.)
[image]

There is my question: Let $L$ be a separable metric space with a Borel regular outer measure $\mu^{*}$ such that $\mu^{*}X = 1 $.

how should I alter this proof if I want to prove it for the metric space $L$ instead of an interval $I$ ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm puzzled how they get the second inequality in (3.4), which they claim is "clear".  If you define $\| f \|_X:=2\| f \|_{L^\infty(I)}$, doesn't that satisfy all of the listed properties of a BFS? (I assume their definition of $\|f\|_{C(I)}$ is supremum norm, based on the later part of proof)

Comment: I mean I realize you can use property (5) to get a weakened form of the second inequality in (3.4), where you scale the right hand side by a constant $\|\chi_{[0,1]}\|_X$, and this weaker inequality should be fine for the proof, so I guess if its a mistake its a harmless one.  Still, a little confusing.

Comment: @MW Please check this one too.  I would be very grateful. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4771228/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-the-subspaces-of-banach-function-space-x

Answer (score 0):

The natural way to adjust the statement is to replace the claim about every interval $(a,b)$ in (3.3) with the same claim regarding every open ball $B\subseteq L$.  Moreover, you want to either assume compactness for $L$, or alternatively assume you are dealing with the space of ***bounded*** continuous functions on $L$, $C_b(L)$.  I will assume the latter from here on out.

Finally, if $L$ includes any ball of $0$ measure, than $C_b(L)$ will include non-identically zero functions $f$ with $\|f\|_X=0$, so then saying $C_b(L)$ is a closed linear subspace of $X$ is essentially false but also sort of nonsensical (whereas the condition (3.3) becomes straight-up false), so to avoid this awkwardness I would simply assume balls in $L$ have positive measure.

Other than that everything in the argument translates naturally if you just replace intervals with balls, with one caveat that in the noncompact case you need to slightly alter the argument.  In the first half of the argument, you cannot necessarily find a point  $x_0$ with $\|f\|_{C_b(L)}=|f(x_0)|$, so instead pick $x_0$ with $|f(x_0)|\geq \frac{3}{4}\|f\|_{C_b(L)}$.  Then pick a ball $B$ centered at $x_0$ where $x\in B$ implies $$|f(x)|\geq \frac{2}{3}|f(x_0)|\geq \frac{1}{2}\|f\|_{C_b(L)}\text{,}$$
which allows you to then reason $$\|f\|_{C_b(L)}\leq \frac{\|\chi_B\|_X}{c}\|f\|_{C_b(L)} \leq \frac{\|2f\chi_B\|_X}{c} \leq \frac{2}{c}\|f\|_X\text{,}$$
in place of chain of inequalities at the top of page 1544.

Comment: I don’t understand why should I assume the compactness of $L$or dealing with the space of bounded continuous functions on $L$?

Comment: Also, why I can’t find a point $x_0$ such that they would be equal?

Comment: Otherwise the continuous functions can be unbounded, so you cannot talk about the sup norm

Comment: You need compactness in order for every continuous function to achieve its supremum.  For example, on an open interval, the function $f(x)=x$ never achieves its supremum.

Comment: Can you please tell me, how did you assume that “ if $L$ includes any ball of $0$ measure, than $C_b(L)$ will include nonzero functions $f$ with $\|f\|_X=0$” ?

Comment: @JohnNash Let $B$ be such a ball, then let $f(x)=\text{dist}(x,L\backslash B)$.  $f$ is nonzero only on a nullset ($B$), so apply the last sentence in condition 1).

Comment: Yes but, why is $||f||_{X}$ equal of $0$?

Comment: @JohnNash "apply the last sentence in condition 1)."

Comment: Please explain it properly. why $f(x)$ is nonzero only on a nullset $(B)$ and even if it is, how do you assume that there exists a non-zero function such that $||f||_{X} = 0$ ?

Comment: It is written that $||f||_{X} = 0$ iff $f = 0$ almost everywhere. You are saying that the $f(x)$ you have defined, is equal to $0$ almost everywhere. So what are you saying?

Comment: $f$ is nonzero only on $B$ (which by assumption is a nullset), since for any point $x\in L\backslash B$, $f(x)=\text{dist}(x,L\backslash B)=0$.  Therefore $f$ is equal to $0$ almost everywhere.  I'm not sure how else to say it.

Comment: $f$ is equal to 0 everywhere. So? You said  that there would exist non-zero function such that $||f||_{X} = 0$ . Where is such non-zero function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148724/discussion-between-m-w-and-johnnash).