# Necessary and sufficient condition for the subspaces of Banach Function Space $X$ .

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

There are all the things that are essential in order to understand the proof of the theorem.

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded measurable set in $R^{n}$, denote by $\mathcal M(\Omega)$ the set of all measurable functions on $\Omega$ and let $p \in \mathcal M(\Omega)$ be a function on $\Omega$ with $1 \leq p(x) \leq \infty$ for all $x \in \Omega$. On the set of all functions $f \in \mathcal M(\Omega)$ define a modular $$ \rho_{p}(f) = \int_{\Omega \setminus \Omega_{\infty}} |f(x)|^{p(x)} dx + ess\sup_{x \in \Omega_\infty}  |f(x)|$$,

where $\Omega_\infty = \{x; x \in \Omega, p(x) = \infty \}$, and a norm by $$ ||f||_{p(x)} = \inf\{\lambda \gt 0; \rho_{p}(f/\lambda) \leq 1 \} $$

The space $L^{p(x)}$ is the set of all functions $f \in \mathcal M(\Omega)$ with bounded norm.

By $|E|$ denote the Lebesgue measure of $E$, $E \subset R^{n}$.

There is the definition of Banach Function Space and its subspaces $X_a$ and $X_b$ :

[image]

[image]

It's obvious that $L^{p(x)}$ is a Banach Function Space on $\Omega$.

There is the theorem and its proof: [image]

[image]

There is my question: Let $L$ be a separable metric space with a Borel regular outer measure $\mu^{*}$ such that $\mu^{*}L = 1 $. ( Note that an outer measure $\mu^{*}$ induces a complete measure $\mu$)

how should I alter this proof if I want to prove it for the metric space $L$ instead of $\Omega$ ?  ( Is there any need of alteration?)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see no definition for $X_a$, $X_b$, or $X_c$.

Comment: We don’t need $X_c$ in this proof

Comment: I’ve meant that $X_A = X_a, X_B = X_b$ @MW

Comment: @MW I have added an important condition for space $L$, that an outer measure induces a complete measure $\mu$. This could be helpful  for you.